# Veg Burger Advice, Am i missing something?

Tags: flavor, microwave

I used to eat burger at home rather than buying from MCDonalds. But i feels the taste can be improved. I am mentioning my method now. Please help me improve it as the Burgers are not crunchy.

1. I used to buy Empty Burgers Buns from Market (Have seeds on top)
2. Buy Ready made Patty from Reliance Fresh store
3. Buy Amul Cheese Slice from Store.

Chop onions in slices
Chop Cucumbers in slices
Chop Tomoato in slices

Now Cut the burger in half. Add a tomato ketchup sauce layer, Mayonaise, Salt, Sometimes (Pudina/Mint Ready Made sauce) and patty and slice, onions, tomato, etc

Then put in on Frying PAN, add some oil, put the burger and try to press it. The change the burger side and done.

I tried putting in Microwave also (But the burgers become so soft and start to break while eating)

Question:
Is my cooking method wrong, or i am setting microwave setting wrong (what will be the temp, microwave/grill) etc

I prefer to avoid long tasks.

Comment: Your question is very confusing as it looks like you are using the term "burger" for both the burger patty and the burger bun.

Comment: @Jay Sorry for the mis understanding. I have ready made burger patty and burger bun both, but asking for cooking method and some spices we can add to make it more better

Comment: Hello Kamal, asking which spices to add is off topic. You can add any spices, and it is up to your personal preference to decide if you like the combination or not. The rest of the question is OK though, so I didn't close, just removed the off topic part.

Comment: is the "Ready made patty" cooked or raw? Do you put the whole hamburger including the bun and the vegetables into the frying pan, or just the patty?

Comment: @KateGregory Hi! the ready made patty is raw, we put it in heated oil and it is ready as yummy to eat

Answer (score 3):

To get crunchy buns, you can toast them in an oven beforehand. Here is how I do it:
Take the bun out of the package, slice it open and put it in a preheated oven (180C / 350F) for about 5-8 minutes. Keep an eye on them!

Depending on the brand and model, you could also put the bun halves in a toaster.

Then assemble your burger however you like. I would not fry it afterwards.

Comment: Sounds great. I will try this. +1 for the advice